# Exporting oracle table on AWS RDS that contains blobs and import into offline database

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, export, rds

My scenario:

Database 1: Oracle on Local server offline, no internet access.

Database 2: Oracle RDS on AWS so no file system access to this one.

I need to export a table containing blobs from the RDS instance to my offline database.  I'm having trouble finding any documentation on doing this.  I only see steps for importing into an rds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to take several steps.

1. Create a free instance of EC2(1 CPU core, 1G RAM, 30GD HDD ) or a
   paid instance with a large disk and CPU.
2. Install a free database version of the Oracle XE version on EC2 instance(It is very easy and fast)
3. Export a table containing blobs from the RDS instance to DUMP
   directory. Use `DBMS_DATAPUMP` to create a dump file.
4. Create database link on RDS instance between RDS DB and Oracle XE DB.
5. Copy the dump files from RDS instance to  Oracle XE DB on EC2 uses
   the `DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE` via database link
6. Copy files from the DUMP directory Oracle XE on EC2 instance via the
   sftp to local PC.
7. Copy the dump files from your local PC to offline database DUMP
   directory
8. import dump files into offline database